# How can make 2 ways binding bwtween SVG and inut elements

Tags: javascript, svg

I've the below code, where I draw 2 SVG rects, and upon clicking each one I can change its size, the size is reflected directly in the input fields above (for the clicked rect), thi is the first part of my requirements and it works fine.

```js
        let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg.setAttribute("class", "octicon octicon-star");
      //  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 14 16");
        svg.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
        svg.setAttribute("width", 240);
        svg.setAttribute("height", 160);
        svg.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        let barThickness = 20

        let orders = [100, 152];
        //orders.forEach((element, index, array) => console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element) )
        orders.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element)
            let r = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
            r.setAttribute("x", 0);
            r.setAttribute("y",(barThickness+10)*index+0);
            r.setAttribute("width", element);
            r.setAttribute("height", barThickness);
            r.setAttribute("fill","black");

            let isDrawing = false;
            let x = element
            let mousePosition = 0

            r.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
                e.path[0].setAttribute("fill","red")
            });

            r.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
                e.path[0].setAttribute("fill","black")
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    isDrawing = false;
                }
            });


            r.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
                isDrawing = true;
                console.log(e.path[0])
                document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
                document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")
            });

            r.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
                document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")
                    
                    if(e.offsetX>mousePosition) {
                        x++
                    } else if(e.offsetX < mousePosition){
                        x--
                    }
                    mousePosition = e.offsetX
                    r.setAttribute("width", x)
                }
            });

            r.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
                if (isDrawing === true) {
                    document.querySelector('#from').value = r.getAttribute('x') //e.path[0].getAttribute("x")
                    document.querySelector('#to').value = r.getAttribute('width') // e.path[0].getAttribute("width")
                    isDrawing = false;
                }
            });

            svg.appendChild(r);
            document.body.appendChild(svg) 
        
        }  )
```

```html
    <div>
        <label for="from">From:</label>
        <input onchange="xStart(this.value)" type="number" id='from' name="from">
        <label for="to">To:</label>
        <input onchange="rWidth(this.value)" type="number" id='to' name="to">
        <br><br>
    </div>
```

The second part of the binding I want, is to be able to change the width and starting point of the clicked rect from the input fields.

I I've single rect to be controlled, I can do it using:

```js
const svgRect = document.querySelector('svg rect')

function xStart(XS){
  svgRect.setAttribute('x',XS)
}
function rWidth(RW){
  svgRect.setAttribute('width',RW)
}
```

But my point is how can I make the input fields remember the latest clicked rect (which sent its data to the input fileds) so that I can control it back?

Comment: Don't use `const` and set value of `svgRect` to the clicked `r` in the click handler. https://jsfiddle.net/kfjp13xz/

Comment: If you paste an SO Snippet then please make sure it works, there is no xStart defined in your snippet